# Turning on Anonymous Authentication, but IIS is still sending 401 with kerberos/windows auth request

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

Ok, so on my new site bob.testing.com, I set it up as anonymous authentication. Under it, i have a folder called apps. That's not an app, and there's no configuration on it. Under apps, I have a folder called MyApp. Originally, I set this up as Windows Authentication, but later I needed to update it to Anonymous. If I rename this folder to MyApp2 and create the application it works with Anonymous Authentication. When I rename it back... it sends back 401. I've tested with Fiddler, tried changing browsers, had someone else at work try it. Same results. I've tried recycling app pool, changing app pool, restarting IIS...

Anyone know how to delete whatever information IIS has cached about this application? I'd prefer not to have to rename and refactor my other apps for this item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after posting; I actually looked here:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

It was listed with two location path's. I ended up just deleting both and then setting it up again as an application. It appears to be working for now...

Looked something like this:

```
<location path="bob.testing.com/apps/MyApp">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```